# not found: value assemblyJarName assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value.replace(' ','-')}-${version.value}.jar"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt-assembly, uberjar, fatjar

I am trying to create a fat jar, using SBT. it always gives an error as:

> not found: value assemblyJarName
>   assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value.replace(' ','-')}-${version.value}.jar"

my build.sbt looks this:

```
name := "SparkExamples1"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-streaming" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core_2.11" % "2.4.5"
assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value.replace(' ','-')}-${version.value}.jar"
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala= false)
```

my assemebly.sbt looks like this---

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.10")
```

scala version is 2.12.8, sbt version is 0.13.9.